# session_start() through include another file php

Tags: php, security, session

I have a few questions related to my project. I'm trying to create a secure login page and I am having problems with sessions.

1). Can I include `session.php` from each file? Is it safe?

login.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('session.php');
    //all code
?>
```

session.php:

```
<?php
    $session_name = '...'; 
    $secure = false; 
    $httponly = true; 
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); 
    ini_set('session.entropy_file', '/dev/urandom'); 
    ini_set('session.entropy_length', '512');
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); 
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly); 
    session_name($session_name); 
    session_start(); 
    session_regenerate_id();   
?>
```

2). Is `session.php` safe enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder why you are setting `ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);` twice, and why you do not set the secure flag for the session. If you are asking for security, using SSL should be the basic step to go.

Also I do wonder if you know the implications of regenerating the session id with every request. The usual approach is to only regenerate it when there is some access level elevation, i.e. during a login, or when making use of admin privileges.

Besides these comments, I cannot see anything evil taking place. You do activate reasonable settings.

Comment: ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) twice is just mistake. In php i can only use CURL. Setting SSL is possible only on server ( at the moment i'm working on localhost ). Are you recommend curl to include session.php or just keep it as now ?